# How to prevent update from conflicting repo?

Tags: centos, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

On EC2 / Amazon Linux AMI (Centos based), I created `/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo`:

```
[nginx]
name=nginx repo
baseurl=http://nginx.org/packages/centos/6/$basearch/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

Then I successfully installed nginx 1.4.2:

```
sudo yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="nginx" install nginx
```

Now, when I run `sudo yum update`, I get:

```
---> Package nginx.x86_64 0:1.4.2-1.el6.ngx will be updated
---> Package nginx.x86_64 1:1.2.9-1.11.amzn1 will be an update
```

**NO!**

How do I permanently block the update? (which is actually a downgrade)

Comment: Stop using Amazon Linux.

Comment: @MichaelHampton As Stefan Lasiewski points out and as I've read [elsewhere](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/ConflictingRepos#Disable:Onewrongisonetomany), in this case *nginx* got it wrong. By the way, in general, I am very happy with Amazon's Linux AMI, which I configured for a client years ago (Apache, PHP, MySQL, Shell). Now, I set up nginx on my own EC2 instance, for proxying to Node.js projects (incl. WebSockets).

Comment: Actually it's Amazon that screwed this up, by assigning an Epoch to their nginx package.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for pointing that out. According to `yum info nginx` (repository `amzn-updates`), the `Epoch` tag is set to a value of 1. The package from repository `nginx` has no epoch tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maintainers of third party repositories should name their packages in a way that doesn't interfere with the main repository, otherwise conflicts like this will happen. Conflicts like the above are unprofessional and a sign of poor quality.

Some workarounds are:

#### YUM priorities

You can use [Yum Priorities](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) configure each repo to use a certain priority by assigning  `priority=N` to the repositories listed in the .repo file. Some Yum developers have criticized Yum Priorities. Read the "Cautionary Note" at the bottom.

#### Excluding packages

You can also [exclude packages from certain repositories](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/redhat-centos-linux-yum-update-exclude-packages/). So, add something like this to your main repo. Substitute your package names.

```
[main]
exclude=php* kernel*
```

Comment: Appending `priority=1` to `/etc/yum.repos.d/nginx.repo` did the trick: `No Packages marked for Update`

Comment: Priorities is the only real option you have, since the problem is that Amazon put an Epoch on their nginx packages for no apparent (and probably no good) reason.

Comment: yum-versionlock might be a solution too, but if you don't want to upgrade package from same repo too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use yum update-minimal

update-minimal Works like upgrade, but goes to the 'newest' package match which fixes a problem that affects your system

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to specify packages not to be updated:

`yum --exclude=nginx* update`

Comment: But I do want updates, though only from the nginx repo.